# How to start and maintain a background thread in django hosted by cherrypy?

Tags: django, multithreading

I have a Django project that provides an API. The api provides an information that must be measured over time. So fo example measure every 2 sec for 2 sec. I would like to write a background thread that measures the information and writes it to a place where it can be accessed immediately.
I host django over cherrypy.

I have the following requirements:

- I need to access the Django ORM in the thread. So Django must be setup already.
- Soft requirement: I would not like to write the information to DB after every measurement. I would prefer to write it to a variable that can be accessed from views.py
- If I stop cherrypy with CTRL C, it must be stopped and not blocked because my thread is running.
- My thread must not prevent migrate and makemigrations from terminating.

Here is my current attempt which mets only the first two requirements (CPU measurement only an example):

```
# CPU Monitoring
cpu_usage = 100
def thread_function(name):
    global cpu_usage
    while True:
        cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)
        time.sleep(2)



x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
x.start()
print("CPU Monitoring thread started")


@api_view(["GET"])
def cpu(request):
    disk_object = psutil.disk_usage("/")
    memory_object = psutil.virtual_memory()

    to_gb = 1024 * 1024 * 1024

    result = {"cpu_load_percent": cpu_usage,
              "disk_usage_percent": disk_object.percent,
              "disk_total": disk_object.total / to_gb,
              "disk_free": disk_object.free / to_gb,
              "memory_usage_percent": memory_object.percent,
              }
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

Does anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
def thread_function(name):
    global cpu_usage
    while True:
        cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)
        time.sleep(2)
        #print("measuing CPU " + str(cpu_usage))

        if cherrypy.engine.state == cherrypy.engine.states.EXITING:
            break


x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
x.start()
```

So after som further hours of research I found a solution.
You can import cherrypy everywehre, and it is like a singelton. You get always the same object. So you can check always what your cherrypy is doing at the moment. So if it is exiting, exit the thread.
You can still run django in debug mode without cherrypy. Cherrypy is stopped in that case, so the thread will run.

Also, a question was how to start it bevore someone accesses the first endpoint:
got to your apps.py and import something from views.py. For example import x.
Python will now scan through views.py and start the thread on the way down.